# Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SftpPathNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am facing an issue while copying the azure storage blob data to sftp server. Some of the files are copied but then failed while processing the pipeline. The file is present in the blob storage and sftp server is configured in the sink.

Following is the error

Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SftpPathNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Can't find SFTP path '/Genesys Sample Call Recordings/callrecordings/00QTLVGRKG8BF9E18AU362LAES06QH9J/00QTLVGRKG8BF9E18AU362LAES06QH9J_2021-08-23_13-34-01-00QTLVGRKG8BF9E18AU362LAES06QH9J_fad2973a343a4fe88ddff263533880df_2021_08_23_13_34_02_4Z58Hvt8RxO1jw780NnUfA.mp4'. Please check if the path exists. If the path you configured does not start with '/', note it is a relative path under the given user's default folder '/'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException,Message=No such file,Source=Renci.SshNet,'

Comment: when I tried to copy the same file to sftp server from a local system, it's giving me a "No such file or directory. Error code: 2 Error message from server: No such file" error in WinSCP.

Comment: the error mentioned in the comment is coming for a file with a long name. I am guessing it's something to do with file name size.